Limiting the amount of data used in dev across a dbt project
I'll often insert some jinja logic into a model's SQL file in order to limit the amount of data being used for a dbt run:
select *
from source('web_events', 'page_views')
{% if target.name == 'dev' %}
where created_at >= dateadd('day', -3, current_date)
{% endif %}

This isn't very DRY as I want to apply this across the entire dbt project. Is there a better way to accomplish this logic throughout the project without having to add this jinja block to each SQL model?

Which dbms are you using?

@jarlh I have a particular use case wherein the project is on Snowflake, but I have several other projects on BigQuery as well for which I'd like to apply the same logic

you might want to give this macro a look: https://github.com/adpleach/jaffle_shop/blob/main/macros/minimize_dev_table_size.sql

That's awesome, thanks so much for sharing!

Thank you @AleixCC, you should add that as an answer to the question!

Done, thanks guys!

You might want to give this macro a look: https://github.com/adpleach/jaffle_shop/blob/main/macros/minimize_dev_table_size.sql
As explained in there, it "will apply a 'where' or 'limit' clause to models that are not being run in production as a way of reducing the table size / run time of tables. It works by checking what the target.database is, and implementing minimization logic (either via "datediff" or "limit") when the target database is not the production database."

Where would you add this macro to affect the whole project?
